# Font Awesome Performance

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-awesome

I'm making use of font-awesome 5.6.1 library to populate a table with many rows and columns.  For every row, there are about three fonts.  A font is typically defined as such:

```
<a href="#" class="d-inline" title="Lock Event" onclick=lockEvent()><i class="fas fa-lock"></i></a>
```

However I noticed a massive performance hit after about 50 icons on the screen.  The tables that are being loaded contains sometimes up to 1000 rows, which equals to about 3000 icons.  This takes the Chrome browser about 30 seconds to load, if it does not completely crash (the fonts only).

Is what I'm experiencing realistic performance for the FA library?  Or am I doing something wrong?

**UPDATE**

Further investigation shows the fonts were actually generated as svg's.  Trying to figure out why this happened as I am specifying css fonts as such:

```
 cell1.innerHTML = `<a href="#" class="d-inline" title="Unlock Event" onclick=unlockEvent()><i class="fas fa-unlock"></i></a>`;
```

**UPDATE**

What happened was I pointed to both the FA CSS and JS files.  Thus the browser used the JS code to generate the SVG's.  Make sure you only have the CSS!

Comment: I would imagine that this would be normal as 3000 icons has to be a lot for the browser to handle. While I cannot answer your question, I would suggest looking into either an asynchronous loading system or paging of some sort as the user can't look at all 1000 rows at a time anyhow. This should make your app perform at least some better.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  It is just strange to me as I can easily load 3000 small images with no problem.  However using FA it is a huge problem.  Why such a performance kill?

Comment: Just to rule out the obvious - does the performance go back to where you'd expect it to be when you remove the icons? Rendering a table with 1000 rows could be slow in and of itself. Either way, something like [`react-virtualized`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized) (or an equivalent for your framework of choice) might help, so that you only have to render the rows that are currently visible.

Comment: @JoeClay yes I did test that.  Performance without the icons are as expected (less than one second loading time)

Comment: I have 10000 rendering here: https://jsfiddle.net/tkmap42z/1/ and the performance seems ok, though I'm not sure that this completely matches your use case

Comment: @OliverRadini  Further investigation shows the icons are generated with svg as a child in the <i></> parent.  Your code does not show that using Chrome Developer Tools.  Might be because I'm generting the HTML via Javascript ?

Comment: I have never noticed FontAwesome causing any performance problems at all, though a page with 3000 of *anything* on it is pretty large. FontAwesome is in fact a *font*; the "icons" are glyphs in a font just like the letters in your blocks of text. Once the font is loaded, it's all just CSS to add content via `content:` properties.

Comment: @Pointy there is something strange going on as my fonts are generated as svg's (I saw this when inspecting the icons)

Comment: Well maybe very new FontAwesome versions do things differently than before.

Comment: So with FA version 5 there's some sort of SVG option, but it's described as such (optional).

Comment: @ceds It depends on how the icons are being generated, they can be either as svg's or as a font, [font awesome's documentation](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/other-topics/performance) on this suggests that css fonts are faster

Comment: @OliverRadini I am using css fonts.  Strange that they are generated as svg's.  I will investigate.  This is definitely why I'm having issues

Comment: @ceds seems like that could be the cause of the problems, fingers crossed

Comment: @ceds I was having the same issue. I had maybe ~100 rows, with 5 icons per row. Was using the js version, and it was slow. Switched to scss+svg, still slow. Only when I went to css+webfonts, the page started loading instantly (as opposed to 10 seconds before). Amazing how slow svgs are on the browsers. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you pulling in Font Awesome? If you just include in your head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

You will be able to do what you're doing no problem and it won't generate svg.

Comment: As simple as your answer is it is the correct one.  What basically happened is I included both the css and javascript links without knowing the javascript is what is generating the svg's.  removing the javascript link did the job.  So I'll mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

Include it into your stylesheet, or sometimes uploading the font onto your server helps aswell. It stays on the server so loading it becomes faster, but then again that depends on your server etc.